# Unable to use function in another package in Go app

Tags: go

I have a go app depending on a few packages. However when I try to build my app it says the functions in an imported package are undefined.

File in main package (batch.go) using the functions:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"

    db "bitbucket.org/b***/go-db"
)

// NewBatch creates a new batch
func NewBatch(orderID, employeeID int64) *Batch {
    return &Batch{
        OrderID:    orderID,
        EmployeeID: employeeID,
        Flag:       true,
    }
}

// InsertBatch inserts a batch and all the underlying order lines and additions
func InsertBatch(b *Batch) (*Batch, error) {
    err := db.Save(b)

    InsertOrderLines(b.ID, b.OrderLines)

    return b, err
}
```

File in sonicdb (aliased as db) with the functions:

```
package sonicdb

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

// Scalar holds a scalar value of a database query, i.e. a count on a table
type Scalar struct {
    N int64 `db:"n"`
}

// Repository interface
type Repository interface {
    Get(sql string) ([]interface{}, error)
    GetAndBind(sql string, i interface{}) ([]interface{}, error)
    View(from string, criteria []Clause, selectors ...string) ([]interface{}, error)
    Find(i interface{}, id int64) (interface{}, error)
    FindAll(i interface{}) ([]interface{}, error)
    FindBy(i interface{}, criteria []Clause) ([]interface{}, error)
    FindByOrdered(i interface{}, criteria []Clause, ordering map[string]string) ([]interface{}, error)
    FindOneBy(i interface{}, criteria []Clause) (interface{}, error)
    FindOneByOrdered(i interface{}, criteria []Clause, ordering map[string]string) (interface{}, error)
    First(i interface{}, criteria []Clause) (interface{}, error)
    Count(i interface{}, criteria []Clause) (int64, error)
    Save(i interface{}) error
    Update(i interface{}) error
    UpdateBy(i interface{}, criteria []Clause) (int64, error)
    UpdateFields(i interface{}, fields []*Field) error
    DeleteBy(i interface{}, criteria []Clause) (int64, error)
    OneToOne(rv reflect.Value, c interface{}, join string) error
    OneToMany(parent reflect.Value, child interface{}, mappedBy string) error
    Relations(parent reflect.Value) interface{}
    MarshalObject(i interface{}) (interface{}, error)
}

// Save handles a save action for a model
func (db *Database) Save(i interface{}) error {
    id, err := doInsert(db.DB, i)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    rv := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    if rv.Type().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rv = rv.Elem()
    }
    for j := 0; j < rv.NumField(); j++ {
        field := rv.Field(j)
        fieldType := rv.Type().Field(j)

        if !field.CanAddr() {
            return fmt.Errorf("field `%s` cannot be addressed", fieldType.Name)
        }

        if !field.CanSet() {
            return fmt.Errorf("field `%s` cannot be set", fieldType.Name)
        }

        if index, ok := fieldType.Tag.Lookup("index"); ok && index == "pk" {
            field.SetInt(id)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Errors:

```
./batch.go:20:9: undefined: sonicdb.Save
```

The bitbucket.org packages are imported with 'go get bitbucket.org/name' and are now located in '~/go/src/bitbucket.org/name', which should be correct.

The packages ran on the computer of the previous developer of this project but since I took over, it will not build. It is probably an easy fix but my experience with Go is very minimal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `Save` *function* declared, at least not in the code you shared. You have a `Save` method declared on the `*Database` type, therefore you you have to first initialize the receiver type and call the method using a selector expression.

Comment: If your experience with Go is very minimal you should go through the whole [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that we have a package called `demo`

```golang
package demo

type DataBase struct {
    A int
    B int
}

// function example
func DemoFunc(x int) int {
    y := x + x
    return  y
}

// method example
func (db *DataBase) DemoMethod(x int) int  {
    y:= db.A + db.B + x
    return y
}
```

To access a function or a method from main code, we can do the following,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    dm "github.com/kamolhasan/stackOverflow/demo"
)

func main()  {
    // Now if you want to use the function
    // DemoFunc() from demo package
    // You can use it like following
    value := dm.DemoFunc(34)
    fmt.Println(value)

    // If you want to use DemoMethod()
    // from demo package, you need to declare the object first
    // then call the method like following
    DB := dm.DataBase{
        A: 5,
        B: 10,
    }
    value = DB.DemoMethod(34)
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

All you need to solve your problem is, declare an object of `*Database` type and use the object to call the method. Do something like bellow:

```golang
var obj db.Database
err := obj.Save(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Save()` function is attached to a `Database` struct, not at the package level